# Creating a Task with JavaFX with a 'wait()' inside

Tags: java, javafx

I use javafx, I have a TextField and a Button, when the button is pressed, it saves what is written in the TextField in a String. What I want to create is a method to mark a pause, while waiting for the Button to get pressed.

I have a class named pause.java, where I tried to put a `obj.wait();` and a `notifyAll();` in the event where the button is pressed, but the window isn't accessible during this time, I can't press the button or enter anything in the TextField.

So what I found was to put the `obj.wait();` in a task, then I don't know why but it directly breaks out of the wait.

Here is my pause.java

```
package net.jpajavafx;

import java.util.logging.*;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;

public class pause {
    Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(pause.class.getName());
    MainController obj = new MainController();

    public void waitinput() {
        Task<Void> sleeper = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                synchronized (obj) {
                    try {
                        String write = "Waiting for input...";
                        logger.log(Level.INFO, write);
                        obj.wait();
                        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Done");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        };
        new Thread(sleeper).start();

    }
}
```

How do I have to modify it to make it wait, while still having access to the GUI?

Here's my code simplified for the problem:

AlbumManager.java, where my main is.

```
package net.jpajavafx;


import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;

public class AlbumManager extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);

        primaryStage.setTitle("Album Manager");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        launch(args);

    }

}
```

MainController.java:

```
package net.jpajavafx;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TextArea textarea;
    @FXML
    private TextField textfield;

   Variablesstoring stock = new Variablesstoring();
    
    public void ok(ActionEvent event) {
        String getValue = textfield.getText();
        stock.setEntrystr(getValue);          //here i have something to put in an Int, I put it aside to reduce the length
        textfield.setText("");
        notifyAll();
    }
    
    public void startprogram() {
        int etat = 0;
        int run = 1;
        while (run == 1) {
            textarea.setText("1: launch method");
            pause.waitinput();     // here I want to wait for an input
            etat = stock.getEntrystr();
            switch (etat) {
            case 1:
                //runs a method
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not actually clear to me what you're trying to do here. If the idea is to have a background thread wait until a button is pressed, that seems redundant (why not simply do whatever you're going to do - in the example this is logging the text `"Done"` - in the button's event handler). But anyway; you are waiting on the object `obj` you created; in the code you posted there's no possible way for any other code in your application to have a reference to that object, so no possible way to call `noifyAll()` on it. Can you create and post a [mre]?

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the edit, but it really doesn't make it any clearer. First, you need to call `notifyAll()` on the same object on which you called `wait()`, which obviously isn't the case. But it's still not really clear what you're trying to do; where is `startprogram()` called (and, importantly, on which thread)? This just looks like completely the wrong solution to whatever it is you're trying to do.

Comment: I actually had a working program on Swing, and wanted to move to javaFX, so I added a "start" button, with inside what was in the 'Main' before, and before I had a method to wait with a While, but With JavaFX it just makes the window crash, so I'm trying to find a way to wait for the Ok button to get pressed.

Comment: Why though? Why do you need to "wait for the Ok button to get pressed"? Why not just move the `switch` statement to the `ok` method?

Comment: The Switch has a few cases that each launch methods where I'll ask the user for information to save in a database, so I use the Ok button a lot inside the methods launched by the Switch

Comment: That... seems completely irrelevant to what I'm trying to say.

Comment: stick to java naming conventions, always :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not clear what you're trying to achieve here that needs a separate thread: all the separate thread seems to try to do is wait until the button is pressed, and then execute some code. That functionality is already provided by the event management system in JavaFX (and the same is true for any UI toolkit): just execute the code in the event handler.

(As an aside, your use of `wait()` is incorrect, and if you fix that, the thread will never wake up because you are not calling `notifyAll()` on the same object on which you are calling `wait()`.)

You can achieve what you seem to be trying to do simply with

```
package net.jpajavafx;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import java.util.logging.*;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

public class MainController {

    @FXML
    private TextArea textarea;
    @FXML
    private TextField textfield;

   Variablesstoring stock = new Variablesstoring();
    
    public void ok(ActionEvent event) {
        String getValue = textfield.getText();
        stock.setEntrystr(getValue);          //here i have something to put in an Int, I put it aside to reduce the length
        textfield.setText("");
        processInput();
    }
    
    public void processInput() {
        int etat = stock.getEntrystr();
        switch (etat) {
        case 1:
            //runs a method
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Allright thanks for the help, seems like the way I'm trying to wait for the button to get pressed isn't good, I must not wait for the input, but react to it, I'll work on that with what you gave me  :]

Answer (score -2):

You have to [start another thread using a Runnable](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/creating-and-starting-threads.html), so your UI thread does not get blocked while the save-operation completes.

You can do this by placing a listener on the button that will start the save-operation on a new thread when the button is clicked.
The code for adding a listener to a button that starts a new thread would look something like this:

```
//Creating the mouse event handler 
  EventHandler<MouseEvent> eventHandler = new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() { 
     @Override 
     public void handle(MouseEvent e) { 
     MainController controller = new MainController();
     controller.start();
     } 
  };  
//Registering the event filter 
button.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, eventHandler);
```

The code you posted doesn't really do anything. Your call to `waitinput()` only logs and calls `wait()`. `wait()` is not what you want, since this operation is intended for putting a thread on hold until it is notified, not for executing a task in a seperate thread. Remove the `obj.wait()`, and add a listener that calls your logging method when the button is clicked. Also, get rid of the while-loop. The EventHandler will take care of events in the background.

Comment: But the OP *is* starting another thread using a `Runnable`... Also, this is tagged JavaFX, so your AWT code is not really relevant.

Comment: Starting a Runnable for simple tasks does not involve manually calling `wait()` and `notify()`. The link thoroughly explains how to do concurrency java for beginners, which the OP will probably need.
Replaced the code with a JavaFX example (same syntax, just different classes).

Comment: Sorry, but this really is nonsense. You start by saying "You have to start another thread using a Runnable", but that is *exactly what the OP is doing in their code*: `new Thread(sleeper).start()`. And, whatever it is the OP is trying to do, at no point do they ever say they want to start the new thread when the button is pressed. I understand what `wait()` and `notifyAll()` are, and I agree they're probably not what is needed, but I don't think this even begins to answer the question.

Comment: [>at no point do they ever say they want to start the new thread when the button is pressed]

He says he doesn't want the UI to block while the other operation completes. So he obviously needs to start a new thread, otherwise the UI will not respond until the other operation has completed. It is not possible to execute two simultaneous operations on a single thread. He doesn't want the UI to block after pressing the button, so the button press has to create a new Thread. If you think my answer is not fitting, why do you not try to improve on it?

Comment: No, the OP says they (not sure why you assume they are male) want to have a thread that waits until the button is pressed, and then performs an action. There's no indication that action is long-running (it's the waiting that's long-running). *"If you think my answer is not fitting, why do you not try to improve on it?"* I did, an hour before you posted that comment, and my solution (don't use a thread, react to the button press) was accepted by the OP.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your post, my bad. Also, I am assuming he identifies as male since his nick is TheGlizzyGladiator, not TheGlizzyGladiatrix.